# Char pointer weird expression in c

Tags: c, pointers, char, expression

I would like to know why this code is running.

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        char* c = "1234567";
        printf("%c\n", 5[c]);

        return 0;
}
```

result:

6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are confused with the `a[b]` syntax, then just refresh your C knowledge.

`a[b]` is defined as `*(a + b)` and since `a+b` is the same as `b+a`, so is `a[b]` and `b[a]`.

Answer (score 0):

In C , array indexing works as follows e.g a[i] it is actually interpreted by compiler as      *(a+i) so it can be written as *(i+a) as addition is commutative.
hence a[i] == i[a].